# How to deal with slow Web services?

Tags: android, multithreading, web-services, android-asynctask

I have created a webserivce using C# on .NET and I'm consuming the same in an android application. At times while testing I notice that the web service is annoyingly slow and does not show results for minutes altogether. I don't want to put my user through this behavior of the application.

I am basically looking for a way such that the communication between the application and the web service can become faster.

PS: I am using asynctask function already to provide a separate thread while calling the web service. STILL it takes minutes at times to extract results from it. 
Any help is appreciated!:]

Comment: which library are you using to access web service in android..?

Comment: I am using ksoap2 as of now.

Comment: it is good, check it to run it in browser first which will give you idea about the speed in other case you have not handled your soap method correct some exception would be there as brain said...

Comment: follow this for your soap method ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569807/android-send-data-to-a-net-webservice/16570082#16570082

Comment: It returns the expected results in appropriate time when I test the same on SoapUI or on a browser, what I'm aiming at is improving the speed between my application and the web service end.

Comment: ok..you mean to say that you are getting proper result at your application but it is slow....so in this I guess you should try to debug/profile your parsing and code. you could find actual fault through this...

Comment: Please notice my emphasis on the word SLOW. There is **no error in the code on either side** (android app or web service structure) only the answer being returned takes forever.

Comment: it is bit strange error, I have not experienced it before..but you could read this for reference, might help

Comment: @Jeet, for the millionth time. Its not an error. Its returning the correct answer but only after a minute which is not very desirable! Also the link that you tried to attach,I cant quite see it.

Comment: first read that artical and then comment...people are discussing about the possibilities for slow access of data from web service..

Comment: Since you're that prompt please read my comment and THEN comment, I've mentioned that I cant see the link you tried to post.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/inVQ18h2n_A

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell if you're saying the web service is slow or if it's just slow to be consumed on an Android device.

If the web service is slow on all devices I'd suggest first eliminating the possibility that it's just the speed of the web connection you're testing on. Obviously there isn't much that can be done about that. If the service is simply slow to respond I'd recommend running some profilers to determine where the slowdown is. If it can't be made more efficient perhaps this is a task better suited to be first requested and placed in a queue. When the task is complete alert the device that the data is ready.

If the Android device is slow I'd also recommend some profiling to determine what's eating up the processor.

Sorry if I'm stating the obvious here but these are the only options I can think of.

Comment: Hey, I'll keep these pointers in mind. I am testing the program on an emulator and a tablet and it seems to go slow on both, however when I try testing on SoapUI or a browser it gives swift response. Im gonna try ruling out the possibilities you listed. Thanks!